# binding adapter to list view

Tags: android

```
if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
        do{
            int nameidx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int Ididx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
            String strName=cur.getString(nameidx);
            String strId=cur.getString(Ididx);
            if(strId.equals("0")) continue;
            Toast.makeText(this,"Contact Name: "+strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            names.add(strName);
            //result[cur.getPosition()]=strName+"("+strId+")";
        }while(cur.moveToNext());
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_item, names);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

this my code and i am getting error at setListAdapter(adapter) as setListAdapter is undefined. please help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an object of listview

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

then set adapter to this listview object

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`setListAdapter()` works when the class extends the listactivity

Comment: thanks but still its not showing any thing on screen i want to display all contacts names, will you please tell me what to do for that??

Comment: are there any contacts in your device? it will not display anything unless there are contacts in device

Comment: ya i have,its showing me in toast but its not showing in list view what to do after lv.setAdapter(adapter); ???

Comment: use this adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names); and if this doesnt works post your list_view_item.xml content here